# How to save the value of the variable after closing the form

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

In WindowsForms I have an independent class **Indicators.cs** and a form **Food**. In the class I have a **variable**, which I'm changing in the form.

When I open the form, changing the variable, close the form and open it again (without closing the program), then the value of the **variable** is old. Why so?

**Form:**

```
namespace WF
{
    public partial class Computer : Form
    {
        Indicators indicators = new Indicators();

        public Computer()
        {
            if (indicators.isComputerAlreadyRunning == false)
                indicators.isComputerAlreadyRunning = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Indicators.cs**

```
namespace WF
{
    class Indicators
    {
        public Indicators()
        {

            this.isComputerAlreadyRunning = false;            
        }

        public bool isComputerAlreadyRunning;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you instantiate your Indicators.cs object?  If it's inside your form, then its scope is only there and it will disappear when the form gets closed.

Comment: @intracept Yes, it is inside the form, but I need it to get access to the variable

Comment: You'll need to then instantiate the Indicators class outside of your form.  You can pass a reference to the object it to your form so you can access the variable.  Then it will exist beyond the scope of your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method in the form class that shows the form and returns a result.  This is similar to the MessageBox.Show method.  In the example below the FoodForm has a method called ShowForm.  This method returns a custom class called FoodFormResult that has all the results needed from the form after it closes.

```
public FoodFormResult ShowForm()
    {
        return new FoodFormResult(
            ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK, 
            _indicators);
    }
```

Every time the form class is created (ex. new FoodForm()), all the existing values in the form are lost.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this..You can create a delegate, save to form's resources, save to external file, save to settings/Appconfig file..So on..

And another but not much recommended for security reasons option is that : You can Create an internal or public static variable in main method of the application..Then when you need set to this variable..

And when you need to call that variable :

```
//Your main method example
static class Program 
{
   internal static bool AreYouOKAY = false;
   // or public static bool as your needs

   static void Main ()
   { 
       ........
   }

/// And in your form

Program.AreYouOKAY = true;

// After your form closed.. from another form just call as above

if(Program.AreYouOKAY)
{
  MessageBox.Show (" Yeah! I'm Ok!");
}
```